# Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_101-b00: Java 1.8 or later is required. After updation to Android Studio v2.2.0 (September 2016)

Tags: android-studio

I have updated android studio to 2.2.0 . It is is not going to restart again it prompt for "Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_101-b00: Java 1.8 or later is required."

I am using jdk 8 .

**echo $JAVA_HOME**

***/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle***

[image]

Comment: go to `File -> Project Structure` what version do you see?

Comment: after update  to Studio v2.2.0 (September 2016) . It is not restarting jst shows prompt

Comment: In Ubuntu the "desktop" entry needs to be updated/removed. In my case, I edited: `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-studio.desktop`

Answer (score 4):

**I had the same problem under Ubuntu system. In my case problem was solved in few steps:**

1. **Delete old android-studio**
2. **Install java 8**

[Commands for java 8 installation]

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

[Verify installed java]

```
$ java -version

$ javac -version
```

[Command for set java 8 as default]

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

3. **Remove old java versions from** [root]/usr/lib/jvm location

[In my case for java 7 version]

```
rm -r java-7-oracle
```

4. **Restart your computer**
5. **Install Android Studio as mentioned in** https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

Answer (score 3):

The following steps solved the problem for me (Android Studio running on Windows Vista):

1. Upgrade Java JDK to 1.8. [Download link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
2. Update JAVA_HOME enviroment variable: Go to Start menu > Computer > System Properties > Advanced System Properties. Then open Advanced tab > Environment Variables. Select JAVA_HOME (or create one if missing) and Edit to point the new JDK folder ([here is a good tutorial](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/installing-android-studio)).

Now you can enjoy Android Studio.

Comment: This worked for me.  Windows 7 running on a iMac with Virtual Box.

Comment: I had set the environment variable STUDIO_JDK and had to adjust this one as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows and experiencing this, make sure that you run the studio executable that matches the bitness of your jdk installation.

So, if you have the 64bit JDK installed (which you should) then make sure to run studio64.exe

Answer (score 1):

1. Install java-8 (open JDK or Oracle JDK)
2. Update JAVA_HOME environment variable (to point java-8)
3. Delete Android Studio Shortcut from desktop
4. Start Android Studio from cmd (by executing the "path-to-android-studio-folder"/android-studio/bin/studio.sh)
5. This will run Android Studio. You can re-create shortcut from Android Studio->Tools->Create desktop entry...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a system variable JDK_HOME with value c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-xxxxx\ worked for me. The latest Java release can be downloaded here.

Additionally, make sure the variable JAVA_HOME is also set with the above location

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in desktop launcher task.
initially it was

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=AndroidStudioWorkSpace - [~/AndroidStudioWorkSpace] - Android Studio 2.2
Icon=jetbrains-studio
Path=/home/nilesh/Drive/Software/android-studio/bin
Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:./../lib/boot.jar -classpath ./../lib/bootstrap.jar:./../lib/extensions.jar:./../lib/util.jar:./../lib/jdom.jar:./../lib/log4j.jar:./../lib/trove4j.jar:./../lib/jna.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -da -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=./studio64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/nilesh/java_error_in_STUDIO_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/nilesh/java_error_in_STUDIO.hprof -Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.2 -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true com.intellij.idea.Main
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
~
```

I changed it to

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=AndroidStudioWorkSpace - [~/AndroidStudioWorkSpace] - Android Studio 2.2
Icon=jetbrains-studio
Path=/home/nilesh/Drive/Software/android-studio/bin
Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:./../lib/boot.jar -classpath ./../lib/bootstrap.jar:./../lib/extensions.jar:./../lib/util.jar:./../lib/jdom.jar:./../lib/log4j.jar:./../lib/trove4j.jar:./../lib/jna.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -da -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=./studio64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/nilesh/java_error_in_STUDIO_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/nilesh/java_error_in_STUDIO.hprof -Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.2 -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true com.intellij.idea.Main
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
~
```

I changed Desktop launcher task to execute by java 8

Answer (score 0):

**Brief:**
Check ~/.profile (rather than ~/.bashrc) to set your environment variable pointing to the jdk 1.8 folder.

I happened to have this problem when I update Android Studio from version 2.1 to version 2.2 under Ubuntu.

You could check studio.sh under the installation folder of Android Studio to see how it checks the Java version. It says:
**Locate a JDK installation directory which will be used to run the IDE.
Try (in order): STUDIO_JDK, ../jre, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, "java" in PATH.**

The shebang in studio.sh is: *#!/bin/sh*
You could check if any of the environment variables, $STUDIO_JDK, $IDE_HOME, $JDK_HOME, $JAVA_HOME in the file ~/.profile (rather than ~/.bashrc) locates a previous version of Java.

In my case,  I specified $JAVA_HOME to the location of Java 1.7. After modifying $JAVA_HOME to the location of Java 1.8, I could launch Android Studio again.

**Remind**: To reload ~/.profile it needs to logout and login.