# Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_55-b13: Java 1.8 or later is required

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a laptop with a small `C-Drive (SSD)` and a big `D-Drive (HDD)`. On my `C-Drive` I was running out of space so I tried unistalling some of the programs on that drive and reinstall them on the `D-Drive`. One of those programs was Android Studio. After Android Studio was installed and set up I tried to open Android Studio, but when I did I got the error message:

> Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_55-b13: Java 1.8 or later is required.

I've tried some things, like setting my `JAVA_HOME` enviroment variable but nothing seems to work. I think the problem has something to do with Android Studio being on my `D-Drive` and Java on my `C-Drive`.

I hope that someone has a solution for this, in any case: thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling Java 7?

Comment: If you´re on Windows, have a look into the Path variable, is there a link to your Java installation?

Comment: This appears to have been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612981/cannot-start-under-java-1-7-0-101-b00-java-1-8-or-later-is-required-after-upda

Comment: @shmosel I don't have Java 7, just 8

Comment: @TobiasH. I don't, should I have a link there?

Comment: @DaveRlz I had looked around before and found a lot of answers that didn't work, so I made my own question, but one of the answers in that question works for me, I had a 64 bit jdk and I runned an 32 bit Android Studio, it's fixed know if you post that as answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have both JDK and Android Studio in the same architecture installed like 32bit or 64bit. This could lead to problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall `java7` and install `java8`
2. set `JAVA_HOME` for 8.
3. Restart and try again. 
   Or else try this link. [Click here](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html). Hope this one helps.

Comment: You can leave java 7 where it is - it is common to have multiple installations of java, you just need to set environment variables to point to the correct one.

Comment: I only have java7 installed, to be more precise my jdk version is: 1.8.0_111

Comment: you mean only java 8?. If so check whether it is 64bit or 32bit. Like if you have 64bit Android studio you much install same bit of java. And also cross check whether you have installed **jdk or jre**. Also check if you have set path. **JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111 and for path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin**